# Django daphne: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django, django-channels, daphne

When i try to run
`daphne -p 8001 messanger.asgi:application`
I get this error: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
If i run server without daphne, I get this error: Listen failure: Couldn't listen on 127.0.0.1:8000: [Errno 48] Address already in use.

This is my settings .py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "channels",
    "chat",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    'django_extensions',
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = "messanger.asgi.application"

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [os.environ.get("REDIS_URL", "redis_url")],
        },
    },
}
```

This is my asgi.py:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "messanger.settings")
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()
django.setup()


application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Django's ASGI application to handle traditional HTTP requests
    "http": django_asgi_app,

    # WebSocket chat handler
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns)
        )
    ),
})
```

This is my consumer.py:

```
class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["room_name"]
        self.room_group_name = "chat_%s" % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name, self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json["message"]
        author_id = text_data_json["a"]
        chat_id = text_data_json["chat"]

        message_create = Message(content=message, author_id=author_id, chat_id=chat_id)
        message_create.save()

        print("message:", message, "author_id:", author_id, "chat_id:", chat_id)

        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                "type": "chat_message",
                "message": message,
                "author_id": author_id,
                "chat_id": chat_id
            }
        )

    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event["message"]
        author_id = event["author_id"]
        author_username = User.objects.get(id=author_id).username
        chat_id = event["chat_id"]

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            "type": "chat",
            "message": message,
            "chat_id": chat_id,
            "author_id": author_id,
            "author_username": author_username
        }))

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend in asgi.py you move the get_asgi_application() directly inside the Router:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        ...
    }
```

And are you running both WSGI and Daphne servers? Websocket functionality will not work with WSGI so Daphne is meant to be your web server replacement. To clarify, Django channels functionality will not work with WSGI.

This issue is most certainly because another server is running in the background in another terminal, possibly Django's development server on localhost/127.0.0.1:8000 or Daphne.

You said you tried running daphne on port Daphne -p 8001 so the Daphne server should start on 127.0.0.1:8001, perhaps you typed 8000?

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do its move models import under django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()